# Xcode 6.3.1 "A signed resource has been added, modified, or deleted" issue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

My xcode version is 6.3.1, my app is a swift project with a WatchKit target.

Xcode showed this message "A signed resource has been added, modified, or deleted" when I ran it on my iPhone 6.

It works fine on iPhone 5s, iPad and simulator, so I guess this is not a certificate issue, right?

I tried deleting the "derived data" suggested in the question [xcode 6 beta 7:A signed resource has been added modified or deleted.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25639270/xcode-6-beta-7a-signed-resource-has-been-added-modified-or-deleted)

After I delete the "derived data", the first time I run, it stopped automatically after "build succeeded"(the app didn't install to my iPhone), when I ran it again, the message showed again.

I also tried restart Xcode, Macbook, iPhone 6, still the same.

Comment: I have the same problem, my app is a OC project with a WatchKit target.

Comment: I have this problem for projects with cocoapods. Do you guys use that?

Comment: @honcheng yes, also in the target of WatchKit extension. I found this issue https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/790 , but didn't find a perfect solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you use coaoapods, this commit of cocoapods can solve part of this problem

> https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/3390
>
> If this link is invalid
>
> Edit $COCOAPODS_DIR/lib/cocoapods/generator/embed_frameworks_script.rb

```
66 - echo "rsync -av --filter \"- CVS/\" --filter \"- .svn/\" --filter \"- .git/\" --filter \"- .hg/\" --filter \"- Headers/\" --filter \"- PrivateHeaders/\" ${source} ${destination}"
67 - rsync -av --filter "- CVS/" --filter "- .svn/" --filter "- .git/" --filter "- .hg/" --filter "- Headers/" --filter "- PrivateHeaders/" "${source}" "${destination}"
66 + echo "rsync -av --filter \"- CVS/\" --filter \"- .svn/\" --filter \"- .git/\" --filter \"- .hg/\" --filter \"- Headers/\" --filter \"- PrivateHeaders/\" --filter \"- Modules/\" ${source} ${destination}"
67 + rsync -av --filter "- CVS/" --filter "- .svn/" --filter "- .git/" --filter "- .hg/" --filter "- Headers/" --filter "- PrivateHeaders/" --filter "- Modules/" "${source}" "${destination}"
```

// line number may change.

But still need to delete some data (include ModuleCache and YourProject-xxxx) in

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
```

every-time before you compile your app.

Comment: it works, thanks, @mgbaozi ! for the every-time deletion, you can add it to pre-action of build stage in scheme.